# triggering builds of several items at once

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have several items in Jenkins and I'd like to trigger a build in each one of them, once I hit build in a different item. I'd like it to happen in parallel.

meaning - today I have item x, item y, item z.
when I want to run them all together, I have to open a different tab for each one, and then hit the build button in each one, at once.
now I'd like to have a different item, that when I hit the build button, it will trigger the builds in all of my items, and the builds of all the items will run simultaneously.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes from one Job you can trigger all other Jenkins jobs. More details can be found in this [Jenkins Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)

Suppose you have `item-x`, `item-y`, `item-z` and `trigger-all` jobs in Jenkins and your goal is it triggers all the job when `trigger-all` is build.

trigger-all **Jenkinsfile** will look like this

```
node {

  stage('trigger-all') {
     build job:"item-x",parameters : [], wait: false
     build job:"item-y",parameters : [], wait: false
     build job:"item-z",parameters : [], wait: false
  }
}
```